# Eclipse code format merge to repository

Tags: eclipse, repository, code-formatting

I like working on Eclipse IDE and like to work in a code format that suits my style.

But the real problem starts when you take over a project and then formatting makes it a real pain to merge the code into repository and eats a lot of time and eye ball movement to make sure its white space coz of format change and nothing creeps into the repo accidentally.

There is a way to add "Pref->General->Compare/Patch->Ignore white space" but still eclipse compare does a bad job.

how you do you guys deal with this situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i would do, before i start to work and make changes to the existing code, i would format the code and do a commit as is, then start working on the new revision.

Like this it will be much cleaner when comparing, and committing the actual changes.